# MsTests MVC5 Controller not triggering OnAuthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, tdd, bdd

I'm testing controller actions on my current project. Got a method to mock the logged user so I can control access to the data itself, on one of the methods I forgot to mock the user and I got surprised, instead of getting a redirect (defined behaviour for non-anonymous actions when you are not logged), the action executed perfectly.
I debugged and found out that the OnAuthorization method is not being called (all my controllers inherit from a custom controller which overrides it.

Here is the offending test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetOffersUserCanImprove()
{
    ContractsController controller = new ContractsController();

    ViewResult result = controller.ReceivingImprovements() as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result, "No se pudo acceder a la página de recibir mejoras.");
}
```

And the custom controller (it calls the method perfectly when running the application, it just skips it on testing):

```
public class MiComunidadController : Controller
{
    protected LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.EnviromentalFactory();

    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        // Rest of security stuff, non relevant, the execution never
        // reaches this point.
    }
}
```

Any hints on why is this happening and how to make the testing controller follow its lifecycle?

Comment: See http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2009/05/23/aspnet-mvc-testing-a-custom-authorize-filters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behaviour I would expect of a unit test, you are testing the controller action in isolation.  If you want to test the authorisation process and the action together, then that forms an integration test and will require a web hosting environment to house the full web lifetime cycle for mvc.

The way I would test this, is to test the action, then have a test that checks for the presence of attribute, this way you can be warned if someone ever removes or changes the attribute that they are possibly introducing unexpected behaviour.

You can then test your authorisation attribute in isolation too, so you know that it works independently of your controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't really understand the MVC pipeline and how it works.  OnAuthorization does not magically get called simply by calling your Action method.  It gets called by the framework as part of the Request pipeline, and is an integration point.

If you want to test OnAuthorization, you'll have to call it yourself.  If you want to test it as part of a complete action method request, then you have to do it through integration tests.

I suggest you read this article, print the PDF's and keep the posted near your workstation.. they will come in handy.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

Comment: Thanks a lot, this enlightened me.